# What’s a term that means argue on behalf of someone?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases

I cant think of the word. It would mean that a person would stick up for someone verbally.

Comment: I can think of the word *vouch.* Are there any other words that would fit better?

Comment: @GeorgeWhite That was my own immediate thought but there is a question about the verb. The verb, in its usage appears (to me) to be solely used in the context of what is advocated, and seems never to be used in relation to a person or group being represented. 'He is an enthusiastic advocate for the death penalty' etc.

Comment: Advocate often refers to someone representing an individual, not just a cause.  See patient advocate, student advocate and  of course attorneys are advocates for their clients.

Comment: Please add an example sentence or two so that we have enough context to go on here.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite That's the noun. The verb seems not to be used in that way.

Comment: Does "The attorney advocated for his client" seem like something you would never hear? To my US ear it sounds very natural.

Answer (score 3):

Advocate?

A person who puts a case on someone else's behalf.
"care managers can become advocates for their clients"